# 2160p HEVC 4K video not playing

Tags: video, vlc-media-player, codec, 4k-resolution, advanced-format

This video is not playing in pc 
I have tried vlc 3.0016, Media Player classic and pot player but did not able to figure out the correct configuration to run the video.
Any suggestion of any other player or configuration of current player may help. 
**This is my system specs and Media info**\

````
Processor   Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9750H CPU @ 2.60GHz   2.60 GHz\
Installed RAM   16.0 GB (15.8 GB usable)\
System type 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor\
GPU - Nvidia GTX-1650Ti

Below is full media and codec information
D:\movies\video_2160p_DSNP_WEB_DL_DDP5_Atmos_DV_HEVC_MZABI_mp4.mp4\
Format                      : MPEG-4\
Format profile              : Base Media\
Codec ID                    : isom (isom/iso2/mp41)\
File size                   : 997 MiB\
Duration                    : 8 min 19 s\
Overall bit rate            : 16.8 Mb/s\
Writing application         : Lavf58.29.100\

Video
ID                          : 1\
Format                      : HEVC\
Format/Info                 : High Efficiency Video Coding\
Codec ID                    : hev1\
Codec ID/Info               : High Efficiency Video Coding\
Duration                    : 8 min 18 s\
Bit rate                    : 16.0 Mb/s\
Width                       : 3 840 pixels\
Height                      : 2 160 pixels\
Display aspect ratio        : 16:9\
Frame rate mode             : Constant
Frame rate                  : 23.976 (24000/1001) FPS\
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)          : 0.081\
Stream size                 : 951 MiB (95%)\
Language                    : English\
Codec configuration box     : hvcC\


Audio
ID                          : 2
Format                      : E-AC-3 JOC
Format/Info                 : Enhanced AC-3 with Joint Object Coding
Commercial name             : Dolby Digital Plus with Dolby Atmos
Codec ID                    : ec-3
Duration                    : 8 min 19 s
Bit rate mode               : Constant
Bit rate                    : 768 kb/s
Channel(s)                  : 6 channels
Channel layout              : L R C LFE Ls Rs
Sampling rate               : 48.0 kHz
Frame rate                  : 31.250 FPS (1536 SPF)
Compression mode            : Lossy
Stream size                 : 45.7 MiB (5%)
Language                    : English
Service kind                : Complete Main
Default                     : Yes
Alternate group             : 1
Complexity index            : Not present / 16
Number of dynamic objects   : 15
Bed channel count           : 1 channel
Bed channel configuration   : LFE```
````

Comment: Not playing… how? What error or symptom do you get? You do realise 2160 needs some grunt to play.

Comment: Do you have installed the HEVC extension from MS store? https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/hevc-video-extensions/9nmzlz57r3t7#activetab=pivot:overviewtab

Comment: @Tetsujin The symptoms is that only audio is working and there is no video playback.

Comment: @Robert no I did not install that MS hevc-video extension is this extension is compulsory to olay 4k? Or is there any other alternative? Thank you

Comment: If you don't have an HVEC decoder installed players that use the Windows decoder system won't be able to show the video. Try VLC, as far as I know it doesn't make use of Windows decoders and have all decoders built-in.